# Update operation is not performing -Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to develop an application in spring boot + thymeleaf, and I'm able to retrieve the logged in user details in the profile tab from the MySQL database, but when I try to change one or two field details (update) and hit the update button it is showing me an **error message - Fri Sep 04 20:39:47 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported**

see my controller code (I'm using @RestController annotated on top of the class)-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView updateProfile(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, HttpSession session) {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        
        Customer exist = cRepo.findByCustEmail(customer.getCustEmail());

        if(exist != null) {
            if(exist.getCustEmail().equals(session.getAttribute("emailsession"))) {
                
                cRepo.save(customer);
                model.addObject("msg", "User Details has been successfully updated!!");
                model.setViewName("profile");
            }
                
        }else {
            
            model.addObject("exist", "Please enter correct email address!");
            String email = (String) session.getAttribute("emailsession");
            Customer cust = cRepo.findByCustEmail(email);
            model.addObject("customer", cust);
            model.setViewName("profile");
            
        }
        
        return model;
    }
```

Thymleaf code (html) -

```
<div align="center" class="alert alert-success" th:if="${msg}" th:utext="${msg}"></div>
<div align="center" class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${exist}" th:utext="${exist}"></div>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">              
                <h4 class="modal-title">Profile Details</h4>
            
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="myForm" th:action="@{/profile}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> 
                        <input name="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Id" th:field="${customer.custId}" disabled="true" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" th:field="${customer.custName}"  required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" th:field="${customer.custEmail}" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        <input name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" th:field="${customer.custPassword}" required="required" />                 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" value="Update" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I want when user login and visit he/she should be able to check his/her profile(which I'm able to do working code) and when the user wants to update few fields(1-2 based on choice) and hit update he/she should be able to update the details (not create new user or record) because when I use @Controller on top of class then this code work and create new user instead update.**

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is annotated with `@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.PUT)` which makes it a PUT endpoint. However, your request is clearly a POST. If we look at your html form it contains `method="post"`. HTML forms only support GET and POST as valid methods so you need to update your endpoint to be a POST endpoint.

tldr;

```
RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

to

```
RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: When I changed to RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)  it is adding new record( new user) in database. But I wan to update the details because in the profile tab user should update the details not add new. can you suggest now?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your existing question, but what is typically done is passing the primary key of the table through the endpoint and using it to determine if you need to do an insert or an update.  If the primary key is not null you know it should be an update and vice versa

Comment: My question is both error as well as an update query because I'm making an update and having a proper primary key of the table set as not null that means the primary key is already present in the database so it should be overridden not create a new one. can you suggest me, please? I'm new and seeking help with this.

Comment: can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You request mapping in  is POST but Controller has set to accept request as PUT.

```
<form name="myForm" th:action="@{/profile}" th:object="${customer}" **method="post"**>


@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = **RequestMethod.PUT**)
```

Just keep these in similar way both should be same.

Comment: I have made changes and now both the places I have written POST but it is adding the data in the database (new user ) when I try to update one or two fields from there. How can I update instead add a new one?

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: To update - replace -  cRepo.save(customer); With - cRepo.save(exists);

Comment: @AjayKumar Thanks it works, the only additional thing we need to do it to set the values before saving the information.

Comment: Of course you will provide/change some data to update.

Answer (score 1):

Please check what I find and resolve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateProfile(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, HttpSession session) {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        
        Customer exist = cRepo.findByCustEmail(customer.getCustEmail());

        if(exist != null) {
            if(exist.getCustEmail().equals(session.getAttribute("emailsession"))) {
                
                **exist.setCustId(exist.getCustId());
                exist.setCustName(customer.getCustName());
                exist.setCustEmail(customer.getCustEmail());
                exist.setCustPassword(customer.getCustPassword());**
                
                cRepo.save(exist);
                model.addObject("msg", "User Details has been successfully updated!!");
                
                model.addObject("customer", exist);
                model.setViewName("profile");
            }
                
        }else {
            
            model.addObject("exist", "Please enter correct email address!");
            String email = (String) session.getAttribute("emailsession");
            Customer cust = cRepo.findByCustEmail(email);
            model.addObject("customer", cust);
            model.setViewName("profile");
            
        }
        
        return model;
    }
```